# how to use android tabs in the same Activity

Tags: android

Hallo,

Any idea where I can find a simple tabs example?

The Android Developers Hello Views Tab Layout example only details how to use separate Activities for each Tab.

I would like to use tabs to extend a screen of settings without scrolling, i.e. there are too many options for a single screen, so I'd like to split them over two tabs, but still handle them in the same Activity.

Each tab can refer to a separate layout file if that is how it needs to be done,

TIA,

-Frink

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your tabhost instead of passing an intent you can pass a viewID

Comment: @FrinkTheBrave: Here is a sample project demonstrating this technique: http://github.com/commonsguy/cw-android/tree/master/Fancy/Tab/

Comment: Just what I was looking for, thanks.
Is there any way of defining the contents of the tabs in separate xml files (so I can use Layout View in Eclipse to help during design?)
I'll try it myself tomorrow, but I need to go to bed :-(

Comment: You might be able to setContent(R.layout.main1), setContent(R.layout.main2), etc. But I've never used this way before

Comment: Just found out, I can use include statements in my xml to include views in other xml files!

Answer (score 3):

if your tabs don't need to be dynamic you can just load the views in the xml file.  Just like in this example http://developer.android.com/guide/tutorials/views/hello-tabwidget.html